# (SOLVED) Routing in service and controller of symfony 3.4

Tags: php, codeigniter, symfony, service, controller

I am in a situation that when i create a url in my controller as

```
$projectInvestorDecline = $this->generateUrl(
            'project_investor_decline',
            [
                'project' => 1,
                'uuid'=>$sucInvestorContact->getUuid()
            ],
            UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL
        );  dump($projectInvestorDecline);
        die;
```

I am getting the output as

```
"http://localhost:8080/app_dev.php/project/decline/1/526f1de7-83d6-11ea-bef1-00e02d4a14d4"
```

which is correct. But when i created the same url in a service as

```
$projectInvestorDecline = $this->router->generate(
            'project_investor_decline',
            [
                'project' => 1,
                'uuid'=>$sucInvestorContact->getUuid()
            ],
            UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_PATH
        );
```

I am getting the output as

```
http://localhost/project/decline/1/526f15ee-83d6-11ea-bef1-00e02d4a14d4
```

which is different from the first one.
What i am i doing wrong..Could anyone help me..

Comment: Is this run in a console command, by chance?

Comment: I think @msg points to the right direction. In the CLI your request context is missing and you have to set it manually. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#generating-urls-in-commands

Comment: @msg Yes ..And Found that there is something i should do in routing in console commands .Thanks

Comment: @dbrumann Thanks.I found that this was the issue and solved it.Thank you